# Is it possible to make a child component inside a slot to send data to his parent?

Tags: svelte

I'm trying to create a Form component in Sveltejs.
This Form component will use `<slot />` to let his parent (App.svelte) define which Inputs and Buttons should be inside the Form.
The Inputs and Buttons are components too and once the Input component's value changes I'd like to update an object inside the parent Form component and when Button is clicked I'd like to send data back to the App component.

I've tried to read Svelte documentation and solve this problem playing around with `<slot let:name={value}>` but I can't find a way to update Form component when an Input component's value changes.

This is the structure of what I'm trying to do:

App.svelte

```html
...
<Form on:submit={saveReceivedData}>
  <Input name="..." value="..." />
  <Button />
</Form>
...
```

Form.svelte

```html
<script>
...
let data = {}
</script>
...
<form>
  <slot />
</form>
...
```

Input.svelte

```html
...
<input name={name} value={value} on:input={updateDataVariableOnFormComponent} />
...
```

Button.svelte

```html
...
<button on:click={sendDataVariableToAppComponent}>Send</button>
...
```

I can try to send you a full code if needed. But, since my problem is not "what I'n doing wrong?" but "how can I do this?", I prefer to write my question in an abstract way.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a component binding to update data in the parent when the child component changes:

```
<Input name="..." bind:value={someValue} />
```

With that binding, `someValue` in the parent will be synced to `value` in the child.

To notify the parent about *events* in the child, as opposed to state changes, you can either use an [event dispatcher](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/component-events)...

```
<!-- Button.svelte -->
<script>
  import { createEventDispatcher } from 'svelte';
  const dispatch = createEventDispatcher();
</script>

<button on:click={() => dispatch('thinghappened', someData)}>Send</button>
```

...in which case you could listen for the `thinghappened` event...

```html
<Button on:thinghappened={e => doSomethingWith(e)}/>
```

...or you can simply forward the DOM event with `<button on:click>Send</button>` and listen for the click event in the parent with `<Button on:click={handler}/>`.

Comment: Thanks for your help!
Yesterday evening I managed to make it work and I uploaded it on your Svelte REPL. I was planning to link it, but your website is experiencing problems since then and I can't save or edit the files now. So I'll add the code in an answer here. Hope this is not a bad behaviour :D

Comment: P.S. if you have 5 minutes, I'd love to know if that's the right approach. Coming from React, slots are still confusing me.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I wanted to do. I'm honestly not 100% happy about it, but I'm loving Svelte :D

App.svelte

```
<script>
    import Form from "./Form.svelte"
    import Input from "./Input.svelte"
    import Button from "./Button.svelte"
    let data = {
        name: "John",
        surname: "Smith"
    }
    const saveValues = (event) => {
        data = event.detail
    }
</script>

<Form data={data} let:saveMe let:updateMe on:save={saveValues}>
    <Input
        label="Name"
        name="name"
        value={data.name}
        on:input={updateMe}
    />
    <Input
        label="Surname"
        name="surname"
        value={data.surname}
        on:input={updateMe}
    />
    <Button on:click={saveMe}>
        Save
    </Button>
</Form>

<h4>Saved data</h4>
<ul>
    {#each Object.entries(data) as d}
        <li>{d[0]}: {d[1]}</li>
    {/each}
</ul>
```

Form.svelte

```
<script>
    import { createEventDispatcher } from 'svelte';
  const dispatch = createEventDispatcher();
    export let data;
    const saveMe = () => dispatch('save', data)
    const updateMe = (e) => data = {...data, [e.detail.name]: [e.detail.value]}
</script>

<slot saveMe={saveMe} updateMe={updateMe} />
```

Input.svelte

```
<script>
  import { createEventDispatcher } from 'svelte';
  const dispatch = createEventDispatcher();
  export let name;
  export let label = false;
    export let value = "";
</script>

<div class="input-field">
  <input
    id={name}
    name={name}
    value={value}
        on:input={(e) => {
      value = e.target.value
      dispatch('input', e.target)
    }}
  />
  {#if label}
    <label
      for={name}
      class:active={value.length > 0}
    >{label}</label>
  {/if}
  <slot />
</div>
```

Button.svelte

```
<button on:click>
    <slot />
</button>
```

Comment: It's a bit unconventional to pass event handlers around like that — it's not totally clear which component is 'responsible' for each bit of state. Wherever possible it's better to just use the built-in HTML elements for this sort of thing — not least because that way you're making your app more accessible to people who use aids like screen-readers. Here's a single-component app that does the same thing: https://svelte.dev/repl/49b3939ba6ce41a099d960edd58872df?version=3.6.4

Comment: If you *do* need to use components, e.g. for styling, it's still better to stick as close as possible to the built-in stuff you get with the DOM (e.g. `<form>` and `FormData`): https://svelte.dev/repl/34b00c4191a54bc0a7b07c90f76e5ba2?version=3.6.4

Comment: Thanks! I'm very new to svelte and your answers help me understand also svelte's philosophy. I guess that the reason why I was using components is to have all the styles and functions related to forms in one single place. But probably I can achieve a similar result without using components at all, and just writing a method for validation for example and pass it to a built-in HTML form when needed.
Thanks also for your second answer, because it helps me understand how to pass events thought slots in a much clearer way that I did :)